# Can you elevate build in Release Management client for VS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, release-management, ms-release-management

This might be the wrong place to ask this because there's no actual code involved but I am running out of places I could seek help regarding this.

Previously I've been using Octopus where you can create a build and later push it to other environments like QA, UAT, Production etc.

I'm using Release manager now and I can't find such option. I was told the only way is to either push immediately to all environments and leave them pending until I'm ready to approve them (which is dangerous in case someone else approves the release prematurely)

Or I was told I would have to revert my code back to an earlier state, push a release to the environment I want and then move the code forward again.

This all sounds wrong and tedious to me and the Release manager documentation does not offer a clear answer. Ideally I want to make a release to one environment and at a later date elevate it to another.

If someone knows how it could be done, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Release Management supports this scenario.

You create a *release path* that consists of the environments you want to release to and the order you want to release to them. It also captures who is responsible for promoting a release between stages.

You then create a *release template* for a given build definition that will travel along that path. When you create a release for that release template, you choose what build from that build definition will be used.

When you trigger a release, it will go to the first stage in the release path, wait for approvals, then move on to the second stage, and so on.

Comment: Yes I believe this is what we have in place right now. But if you trigger a release directly to one environment, there seems to be no option to push that release to another. You have to trigger a new one (by which time the code will have changed). 
Your scenario only works if you have triggered a release on a predefined release path. 
I might be using it the wrong way, but it seems to me that you either push it everywhere, or only one place. Is that right?

Comment: You **have** to use a predefined release path, the software won't allow you to do otherwise. If you're using one release path per environment, then yes, you're using the software incorrectly.